# Using Arrays or other method to condense redundant elseif conditions?

Tags: php

I have multiple, various elseif conditions that have the same value, is there a way to condense all the conditions to one string that all have their common value?

I have looked all over for an example but only find very complicated, unrelated discussions.

Example:

```
{% elseif "aerospace" in BlogUrl %}     
<a href="url.com/blog_subject_one_subscribe">

{% elseif "aviation" in BlogUrl %}      
<a href="url.com/blog_subject_one_subscribe">

{% elseif "aircraft" in BlogUrl %}      
<a href="url.com/blog_subject_one_subscribe">

{% elseif "jet-engine" in BlogUrl %}        
<a href="url.com/blog_subject_one_subscribe">

{% elseif "fuel-systems" in BlogUrl %}      
<a href="url.com/blog_subject_one_subscribe">
```

This is for an Oracle/Compendium blog categories subscription management workflow. As you can see, multiple categories have one common subscription url.

I'm new to PHP, is there a way to group all the conditions giving them all the common value of the URL in one string, instead of multiple strings with the same value?

Thanks!

Comment: I would add this logic side to a service and just call the result in the view instead. Can add an example on how to achieve this but if to be specific to your case would need more information, like your controller or whichever script is compiling everything to then call the view

Comment: Put them in an array and use `in_array()` to determine if the value is there.

Comment: just make you own function like `somethingInsomething(something,array);` put it into a service and call it in the frontend

Comment: why not just put an array( "aerospace", "aviation", "aircraft" etc.,) then do foreach on it? Break out once found. Exactly the same functionality then.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you have the same a tag in all the if-else paths im wondering why you are not doing something like this:

```
{% if ("aerospace" in BlogUrl || "aviation" in BlogUrl || "aircraft" in BlogUrl ||"jet-engine" in BlogUrl ||"fuel-systems" in BlogUrl ||  %}     

//your code here
{% endif %}
```